# Deleting all new files at the end of the day

Tags: windows-10, networking, file-management, administrator

I am doing some network consulting at my church, and we are looking for a solution to delete all new created files at the end of the day on a Windows 10 Pro computer that everyone uses (Or even wiping the profile at the end of the day).  I was looking for an option in local group policy, but the only thing I could find was deleting a profile after "X" amount of time.  I thought about creating a script and running it in the task scheduler, but I'm not sure if I could set it up to delete new folders that were created by the user, etc. Does anyone have any suggestion or ideas for a simple solution?

**Here is what the network consists of**

- The network consists of about 10 Windows 10 Pro computers (One of which is being used by the admin).
- Each computer has a normal user profile and an admin.
- Each computer has a standard image with the same apps, etc.
- The network is just on a normal workgroup (No domain).
- We don't have much of a budget (So we would like to keep the solution free or very low cost).

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you want a tool like [Deep Freeze](https://www.faronics.com/en-uk/products/deep-freeze/standard) from Faronics.

> Deep Freeze preserves your computer configuration. **Any changes – either malicious or unintentional – are reversed on reboot**. This is called Reboot-to-Restore where each reboot restores the computer to its desired configuration.

It is a paid solution, and [is $45 per machine](https://www.insight.com/en_US/shop/product/DFS0NA1LAPL0W01SN2/FARONICS/DFS0.NA1LA.PL0.W01.SN/Faronics-Deep-Freeze-Standard-Edition---license---1-workstation/)

There is also [Reboot Restore RX](https://horizondatasys.com/create-a-quote/#reboot) which can restore a machine to a known state on every reboot. Again this is a paid solution, in a similar ballpark as Faronics.

I don't think you are going to find an easy free or open source solution for this. There was Windows SteadyState, but it was discontinued in 2010. [This Spiceworks Forum page](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1916330-is-there-an-alternative-to-windows-steadystate) suggests setting up a differencing disk that get discarded on reboot and links to [this Microsoft page on setting up Kiosk Mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/configuration/kiosk-prepare).

The problem is that you will still want to regularly update these machines as security vulnerabilities in the OS and browsers get patched, so it could end up being a lot of work to do that on a regular basis.

Comment: Thank you for advice about the tool Deep Freeze.  I will keep that in mind.  I was able to create a batch file that deletes and re-creates the profile.  It was much easier that trying to write a script that only deletes newly created files and folders.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

So I found a solution.  I just created a batch file that deletes and recreates the profile once a day and set it up to run within task scheduler.  There is an Admin profile and a basic user profile that everyone else uses, so I just stored the script within the admin's profile.  I just tested it and it worked.